# (HTML/CSS) Background renders differently on mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css

I am learning html and css right now and am trying to make a website. I am not making two different websites for desktop and mobile, but I would like to make the one website at least work on both although it will certainly look better on desktop.
My problem is that on desktop I am trying to make the background not scroll with the page but rather have everything else move, that works currently. However, on mobile, either the height spans the whole page of the second site, the width of the background is equal to the width of the screen and is placed at the center of the whole page (doesn't scroll with viewport), or it repeats vertically. Right now the website on mobile looks like the first issue.
Website: https://dafrancc.github.io/dafrancc/theNewOrder.html
background code:

```
body {
  background-image: url("Pt5_ValleyModified.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

Comment: first thing is add a viewport https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 0):

First add this meta tag to the head tag:

**HTML**

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```

Then use CSS to set a different style for mobile devices:

**CSS**

```css
@media only screen and (max-height: 3840px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("Pt5_ValleyModified.jpg");
        background-position: 100% top;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
        color: white;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    }
}
h1 {
    font-size: 8em;
    text-align: center;
}
pre {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
iframe {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
footer {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -4em;
    left: 0em;
    right: 0em;
}
.bottom {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: -10em;
    width: 100.9%;
    height: 7em;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 2em;
    right: 20em;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul li {
    width: 7em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
    margin: 0.1em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border: 0em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transition: 0.25s;
}
ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
ul li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.06);
    background-color: rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.1);
    border: 0.1em solid rgba(9, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    // do your mobile code changes here
}
```